# error on connecting to OpenLDAP using LdapConnection

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, openldap, ldapconnection

```
        using (LdapConnection ldap = new LdapConnection("localhost:389"))
        {
            //ldap.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
            ldap.Bind(new NetworkCredential("cn=manager,dc=wave,dc=com", "secret"));
        }
```

I tried with both with Authentication type as well with authentication type as basic. but it gives an error that 'The distinguished name contains invalid syntax'

One more thing, is that I can't use System.DirectoryServices, because it works perfect only for Active Directory, thats why I am using System.DirectoryServices.Protocol.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimmiet/archive/2010/10/03/10070812.aspx) may shed some light on your problem.  Try this:

```
    using (LdapConnection ldap = new LdapConnection("localhost:389"))
    {
        ldap.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
        ldap.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
        ldap.Bind(new NetworkCredential("cn=manager,dc=wave,dc=com", "secret"));
    }
```